# Unable to use sed to replace text with shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

For some reason, the answer in the post below doesn't work for me.  Any thoughts?
[how to use sed to replace a string in a file with a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230020/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-a-shell-variable)

I'm running CentOS 6.5

```
`NEW="new value"
cat myfile.txt | sed -e 's/old/${NEW}' <-- just replaces 'old' with '${NEW}'
cat myfile.txt | sed -e 's/old/$NEW' <-- just replaces 'old' with '$NEW'
cat myfile.txt | sed -e "s/old/${NEW}" <-- gives the error: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Also sed takes filenames as args, no need for cat. Also `s///` requires three delimiters

Comment: Thank you.  I was using cat just as a way to test this without modifying the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try taking the 's off the sed e.g

```
$ new=N
$ cat > j
one
two
three
$ sed -e "s/one/${new}/" j
N
two
three
```

for a more complete answer try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/environment-variable-substitution-in-sed)

Comment: Thanks!  wrapping the shell variable in double-quotes worked!  Like so:

 sed -e 's/old/'"$NEW"'/'